# TortoiseSVN - Key not valid for use in specified state

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

I am unable to uninstall TortoiseSVN. Every time I do, I get the error "Key not valid for use in specified state". Error message appears again and again, even when I restart and try to install again. How do I resolve this error?

Answer (score 3):

This is not a problem with TortoiseSVN, but an issue with the Windows Installer Service. The installer service for x64 machines seems to be broken after installing a windows update KB2918614 (available somewhere in August).

Current solution: Go to Control Panel -> Programs and Features -> select "View installed update" -> locate update called "Security Update for Windows 7 for x64-based Systems (KB2918614)" and uninstall it. Restart will be required

More details:
http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows8_1-windows_install/kb2918614-breaks-windows-installer-service/3d75a1c2-114a-4241-a527-35b536edc158